# Prevent new activity being logged against inactive accounts

Tags: validation-rule, tasks, event, activities

Our accounts have inactive checkbox. When this is checked users should not be able to create new tasks/events

I tried validation rules like: (on both task and events)

AND(
ISNEW(),
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
Account.Inactive__c = true
)

Users are still able to save new activities. 
Is this even possible with validation rules?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case i would suggest using trigger validation on the child objects. In the beforeInsert context look if the related account has inactive=true then addError to prevent the insertion.